# Percentage difference between 2 images

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing, uiimage

I have an app where I'm taking 2 UIImage instances as input with the goal of providing as output a percentage value indicating how different (or similar). Is there anything in UIKit or Core Graphics that I can use to do this? For example, 100% would indicate a perfect match.

Here's my input data:

[image: [first image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoqUF.png)

[image: [second image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dN2V.png)

I would expect less than 100% for the above, since they are clearly different.

Also open to 3rd party suggestions.

Comment: What do you want to check for simularity? Pixels, image content (both images contain a fish), ...

Comment: I would like to check for pixel similarity. Basically, I'm trying to compare a reference image of an empty signature box with another image of the same signature box, but where a signature may or may not be present. If not present, then images are the same and I conclude there is no signature. Otherwise, if result is less than 100%, I can conclude that someone may have signed the region.

Comment: How I understand you want to know if the images are equal or not. In this case, you can use the `==` operator. `if image1 == image2 {//no signature} else { //signatur}`

Comment: Something like that, yeah. But if they are not equal, I want a value that shows how different they are. For example, my images above have some differences (one has no signature, no light gray bar on top), but also has some similarities (owner signature label, X mark, etc.)

Comment: So what you actually want to compare is the similarity of the signings?

Comment: Not even similarity of signature. Just determine if box has signature (or any marks inside it).

Answer (score 0):

A very very simple way to achive this is to iterate over both images and comapre each pixel. With the width and the height of the pixel you'll be able to get the difference of the pixels as an percentage value.
Here is an example implementation in swift that shows how to iterate over the pixels of an image. It also shows how to get the R, G and B values for each pixel which (so I thnik) should be the base for the comparison:

```
import Foundation
import QuartzCore
import AppKit

let imagePath : NSURL? = NSURL( fileURLWithPath:   "/Users/fabi/Desktop/Test.JPG"    );

if imagePath != nil {

var image = CIImage( contentsOfURL: imagePath )

var imageProperties : NSDictionary = image.properties()


var imageWidth : NSNumber? = imageProperties.valueForKey( "PixelHeight" ) as? NSNumber
var imageHeight : NSNumber? = imageProperties.valueForKey( "PixelWidth" ) as? NSNumber

println( imageWidth?.integerValue )
println( imageHeight?.integerValue )

var bitmapImage : NSBitmapImageRep = NSBitmapImageRep( CIImage: image )

for var w = 0; w <= imageHeight?.integerValue; ++w {
    for var h = 0; h <= imageWidth?.integerValue; ++h {
        var pixelColor : NSColor? = bitmapImage.colorAtX( w, y: h )
        println( "R: " + pixelColor?.redComponent );          
        println( "G: " + pixelColor?.greenComponent );
        println( "B: " + pixelColor?.blueComponent );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to solve for iOS and cannot use AppKit.